# Custom UIBarButtonItem icon stretched

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimage, retina-display

I've got a retina and non-retina printer icon. When I just specify 'PrinterIcon.png' on,

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PrinterIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(printCmdTouched:)];
```

it just using the non retina image on my iPad 3 (third generation). If I specifically specify 'PrinterIcon@2x.png' (x lower cased) I don't see it in the toolbar. If I specify 'PrinterIcon@2X.png' it does show in the toolbar but is stretched horizontally.

Anyway know why?

The retina image specs are:
Image Size:40x40
Image DPI: 299.99 pixels/inch
Color Model:RGB

The non-retina image specs are:
Image Size:20x20
Image DPI:72.00 pixels/inch
Color Model:RGB

I checked the specs in Pixelmator.

Attached are the images.

Anyone know why this is not working?

I'm using iOS SDK 5.1
iOS Deployment Target 5.0
Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 5.1)

[image][image]

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the project. I created a simple test app, added a UIBarButtonItem to the toolar. On iPad 2, the non-retina image displays and on the iPad 3, the retina image is used. Note: I renamed the image to 'PrinterIcon@2x.png'. The x being lower case. Though, I don't believe the case matters so much. I did try using the new named image in my project without any kind of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixe the issue. I cleaned the build and removed the app from the device before debugging again. Now all good.